How to use docker in Coder workspace
Ubuntu-22.04.4
I used curl -L https://coder.com/install.sh | sh to deploy Coder and installed Sysbox and Docker, but still unable to use Docker in the workspace normally. I have added Coder to the Docker user group.
These are the two different templates I tried.

starter template Docker Containers ( I downloaded Docker in the workspace.)
starter template Docker Containers but
image = "codercom/ubuntu-docker:latest"

error
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
How can I modify it so that I can use Docker in the workspace?

You will need to start the dockerd service in the workspace.
You can automate this in the agent startup_script. See our dogfood template for an example.
Also, please note that the codercom/ubuntu-docker image has not been updated in a while. I'd recommend you use codercom/enterprise-ubuntu instead (link), or build your own Docker image.
